# How do I render nested routes for a specific param value in React Router v2?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, nested-routes

I am currently using React Router v2.8.1 in a project and, although I'd prefer to, I don't really have the option of migrating to v4+. I have a component (`Admin`) that deals with showing some content based on the `tab` param in the route, and my aim is to flesh out some extra routing for a specific tab (`"pages"`, for example).

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <Route path="/admin/:tab" component={Admin}>
      <Route path="/admin/pages/edit/:ref" component={EditPages} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

With this setup, the `Admin` component is rendered with props `{params: {ref: '...'}}` instead of the value of `tab` that it matched on, and so it won't show the `"pages"` tab. Since there is no reason for the router to render `Admin` without having a match for `:tab`, I do not understand why this param is being omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround to this using the `getChildRoutes` prop:

```
<Route
  path="/admin/:tab"
  component={Admin}
  getChildRoutes={(location, cb) => {
    const { tab } = location.params
    switch (tab) {
      case 'pages':
        cb(null, {
          path: 'edit/:ref',
          component: EditPages
        })
        break
      default:
        cb(null, [])
    }
  }}
/>
```

I hope this helps anyone who might come across this issue in the future.